# Extra Time not reflected in PostgreSQL EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

Turning on `\timing` in PostgreSQL, I can see the time it takes a command to run.

I've run the same query, with the same database and indexes on two machines and am seeing very different results.

On the first machine:

```
machine1=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO "notes" ("content", "date", "inserted_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ('Something of note', '2015-4-27', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1) RETURNING id;
                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert on notes  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
  Planning time: 0.048 ms
  Trigger for constraint notes_user_id_fkey: time=0.177 calls=1
  Execution time: 0.286 ms
(5 rows)

Time: 2.218 ms
```

On the second machine:

```
machine2=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO "notes" ("content", "date", "inserted_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ('Something of note', '2015-4-27', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1) RETURNING id;
                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert on notes  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
  Planning time: 0.040 ms
  Trigger for constraint notes_user_id_fkey: time=0.118 calls=1
  Execution time: 0.196 ms
(5 rows)

Time: 86.452 ms
```

Two questions:

1) Why is there more time than the planning + execution time?

2) What does that additional time comprise of, that could make such a difference between these machines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is a *server-side* command. It reports *server-side* execution time. You can optionally run it as `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)` if you want just runtime, as the timing overheads that're enabled by default in `ANALYZE` mode will otherwise make the query take longer than it would without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

`psql` is a client application. Its `\timing` command reports *client-side* runtime from sending the query to receiving and processing the results. Importantly, **psql's `\timing` results are affected by client/server round-trip times**, wheras `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is not.

There's also `log_min_duration_statement`, which tells PostgreSQL to log server-side query durations without doing analysis, and while still returning the results to the client. You can ask PostgreSQL to send this information to the client with `SET client_min_messages = 'log';` - however, *only the superuser can set `log_min_duration_statement`* since it affects both logging and client reporting, making it rather less useful. It'd be nice if PostgreSQL could be asked by clients to send server-side timing information along with the query results without requiring superuser.

It looks from your sample output like you're using a single client to connect to two different machines. The result set data size is much the same. So I'd say the difference is very likely round-trip time. Ping each host.